# Pivot wider with merging rows in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I have the data like this:

| id | group | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 2 | 0 | 81 | 0.01 | 81 |
| id1 | 3 | 115 | 66 | 0.05 | 181 |
| id2 | 2 | 0 | 58 | 0.01 | 58 |
| id2 | 3 | 0 | 110 | 0.01 | 110 |
| id3 | 2 | 95 | 81 | 0.03 | 176 |
| id4 | 2 | 40 | 126 | 0.02 | 166 |

and I need to reshape it to df which looks like this:

| id | A_1 | A_2 | A_3 | B_1 | B_2 | B_3 | C_1 | C_2 | C_3 | D_1 | D_2 | D_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 0 | 0 | 115 | 0 | 81 | 66 | 0 | 0.01 | 0.05 | 0 | 81 | 181 |
| id2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 58 | 110 | 0 | 0.01 | 0.01 | 0 | 58 | 110 |
| id3 | 0 | 95 | 0 | 0 | 81 | 0 | 0 | 0.03 | 0 | 0 | 176 | 0 |
| id4 | 0 | 40 | 0 | 0 | 126 | 0 | 0 | 0.02 | 0 | 0 | 166 | 0 |

To do this I used (I set values_from sepretely for each variable A, B, C, D):

```
test <- pivot_wider(data, names_from = group, values_from = A)
```

but the result I obtaied look like this:

```
  id           B   C    D   `2`   `3`   `1`   `4`
  <chr>       <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 id1     0    81    81  0.01 NA       NA    NA
2 id1   115    66   181 NA     0.05    NA    NA
3 id2     0    58    58  0.01 NA       NA    NA
4 id2     0   110   110 NA     0.01    NA    NA
5 id3   95    81   176  0.03 NA       NA    NA
6 id4    40   126   166  0.02 NA       NA    NA
```

Is there any way to correct this so I can obtain the results that I need ( one id = one row) or rather I should use another function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two-step:

```r
tidyr::pivot_longer(dat, -c(id, group)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id, names_from=c("group", "name"),
                     names_glue="{name}_{group}", values_from="value")
# # A tibble: 4 x 9
#   id      A_2   B_2   C_2   D_2   A_3   B_3   C_3   D_3
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 id1       0    81  0.01    81   115    66  0.05   181
# 2 id2       0    58  0.01    58     0   110  0.01   110
# 3 id3      95    81  0.03   176    NA    NA NA       NA
# 4 id4      40   126  0.02   166    NA    NA NA       NA
```

though I suspect there's a way to do it with `names_glue`.

Or a one-step:

```r
pivot_wider(dat, names_from = "group", values_from = A:D, values_fill = 0)
# # A tibble: 4 x 9
#   id      A_2   A_3   B_2   B_3   C_2   C_3   D_2   D_3
#   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
# 1 id1       0   115    81    66  0.01  0.05    81   181
# 2 id2       0     0    58   110  0.01  0.01    58   110
# 3 id3      95     0    81     0  0.03  0      176     0
# 4 id4      40     0   126     0  0.02  0      166     0
```

Neither are immediately filling out missing letter/number combinations.

Answer (score 2):

We may need to expand the data with `complete` before doing the `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
   complete(id, group = 1:3, fill = list(A = 0, B = 0, C = 0, D = 0)) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = A:D)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 13
  id      A_1   A_2   A_3   B_1   B_2   B_3   C_1   C_2   C_3   D_1   D_2   D_3
  <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1 id1       0     0   115     0    81    66     0  0.01  0.05     0    81   181
2 id2       0     0     0     0    58   110     0  0.01  0.01     0    58   110
3 id3       0    95     0     0    81     0     0  0.03  0        0   176     0
4 id4       0    40     0     0   126     0     0  0.02  0        0   166     0
```

Comment: I'm receiving warnings like this: Warning messages - CR is C in my real data:
1: Values in `CR` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list(CR = list)` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = list(CR = length)` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = list(CR = summary_fun)` to summarise duplicates

Comment: @jakim_M probably, your original data may have duplicates for `id and group`.  You may do `library(data.table); data %>%  complete(id, group = 1:3, fill = list(A = 0, B = 0, C = 0, D = 0)) %>% mutate(rn = rowid(id, group) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = A:D)`

Comment: I'm still receiving warinings, this time Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `rn`.
ℹ `rn = rowid(id, laktacja) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = laktacja, values_from = IFLH:DO)`.
x no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric'). Group is factor and must stay  @akrun

Comment: @jakim_M  sorry not clear.  this was based on your example and it is working fine